# Timeseries regression

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, arima

I'm following an   undergraduate course on timeseries using OxMetrics and wanted to reproduce som results in R

Estimating an ARMA(3,3) model:

```
arima(temp,c(3,0,3))
```

using stats package and also TSA package results in following error:

```
Error in arima(temp, c(3, 0, 3)) : non-stationary AR part from CSS
```

Tried to use ML-method:

```
arima(temp,c(3,0,3),method="ML")
```

no error so I get estimates, but not the estimates found in OxMetrics.

Then I tried installing the package FitARMA and used:

```
FitARMA(temp,c(3,0,3),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Which results in the same estimates for the coefficients as when estimated in OxMetrics using exact MaxLikelyhood except for the constantterm.

Then I tried changing fourth argument of FitARMA from FALSE to TRUE:

```
FitARMA(temp,c(3,0,3),TRUE,TRUE)
```

Estimating mean by max.likelyhood and then getting the same estimate for the constantterm but now the estimates for the coefficients change to approximately the same as when using arima in R.

I've already consulted four books on R and I can't really figure out why this is happening. Both OxMetrics and R use BFGS for one. Being quite new to timeseries I'm quite lost...

Comment: Could you give us the actual time series? For R, you can use `dput(temp)` and edit your question to put the result in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time series are tricky to handle, because there are different parameters to estimate: initial values for AR and MA terms on the one hand and the actual AR and MA parameters on the other hand. Often software takes a hybrid approach. For instance, the help page to `arima()` in R tells you: " The default (unless there are missing values) is to use conditional-sum-of-squares to find starting values, then maximum likelihood." Which of course is something different than full ML. I don't know `FitARMA()`, but its help page refers to an article with the title "Faster ARMA maximum likelihood estimation", which also sounds like something that may give different results than other implementations. And even if you do use full ML, the likelihood is not necessarily well-behaved, and the estimation may end up with different maxima for different starting values.

Bottom line: different software may give different results for time series, and this will probably never change. Sad but true.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not familiar with the use conditional-sum-of-squares to find starting values - but it sounds like that might be it. Since FitARMA used full ML as far as I could understand and gave the wanted results (same as in OXMETRICS which uses full ML).

Comment: Was also able to reproduce the results with arima with the "proper" choice of initialvalues. Once again thx.