# How does software generally fit ARMA models?

Tags: arma

When fitting data to get coefficient estimates for ARMA models, how are the MA terms generated by the software to fit the data?

Every time I try to fit some data, wouldn't I get different values, as the MA(1) terms are white noise and are regenerated for every simulation?

From an analytical standpoint also when fitting an ARMA model to a set of data, would I get a unique set of coefficient estimates or is it likely to vary due to this reason?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? When you ask about "Every time I try to fit", are you fitting the same data each time? Or are you generating new samples of white noise? Of course, new samples will yield different parameter estimates. Or are you asking why different software packages yield different parameter estimates on the same time series? If so, this may be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/timeseries-regression/41495#41495

Comment: Let us assume i use the same time series data each time. Now I try to fit an ARMA(1,1) model. for the AR(1) part the data used to fit is certainly known. The next part is the MA(1) part. For the MA(1) part, each time i rerun the program to fit, isnt the data used to fit the MA(1) part always regenerated as it is really white noise? And because this is regenerated arent the coefficients for the ARMA(1,1) going to be different each time i run the program?

Comment: First of all, your software will probably not fit both components in two separate steps, but in a single step. Second, why should data be "regenerated"? The point of fitting a model is to fit it to given data, not to generate new data.

Comment: Well I'm giving the same data to get a ARMA(1,1) fit. But the data to be fitted is a function of a AR, MA term. Like lets say I have a time series Y(t) of 50 data points. I want to fit a ARMA(1,1). Now the Dependent variable (data to be fit) has 49 values and Y(t-1)(AR(1) term) has 49 values. How does the software get 49 values for MA(1) term? By randomly generating? If so a random generator generates different values every time we re run. If that is the case how is consistency maintained in estimating the ARMA(1,1) coefficients.

Comment: The software assumes that you have a zero error for the first period ( of the 50 ). A "guess" is made for the AR and the MA coefficients. Thus a prediction can be made for period #2 using the actual value for the first period and the presumed error (0.0) using the two guessed parameters. This leads to an estimated error for the second period. . A prediction can then be made for the third period usiang the actual value for the second period and the estimated error for the second period. Continue this out to period 50 at which time we have 49 non-zero error terms. Evaluate alternative guesses.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense. So the error terms are based on past errors and not randomly generated by the software. So is there a difference among software's for what they assume for the first error or is it always zero? Also are the initial guesses for AR and MA coefficients different? How much variation in results do these differences in assumptions cause?

Comment: So many questions ! Some procedures avtually reverse the process and then go back to predict(compute) the residuals in reverse order. At the end of the day it is much ado about nothing ! Current procedures are relatively robust to starting values withlittle or no effect. However good software will allow you to specify the 3 stopping criteria ( # of guesses, error SOS convergence , parameter convergence )